# Intermittent issues uploading via FTP (fatal: protocol version) - Connections not being removed?

Tags: centos, ftp, centos7, vsftpd

Client is experiencing intermittent problems uploading files to the FTP server. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

It seems they can login ok (the vsftpd logs show successful logins), but then on attempting file transfers it fails sometimes, with the error:

```
alert write: fatal: protocol version
. 2017-03-20 21:00:06.459 error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
. 2017-03-20 21:00:06.459 wrong version number
. 2017-03-20 21:00:06.459 Disconnected from server
. 2017-03-20 21:00:06.459 Connection failed.
```

(They are using winscp)

The server is setup with vsftpd in passive mode, here is the config:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
xferlog_std_format=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=yes
listen_ipv6=no

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

pasv_enable=yes
port_enable=yes
pasv_min_port=10090
pasv_max_port=10095
pasv_address=**removed**
pasv_addr_resolve=yes

allow_writeable_chroot=YES

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/eastberks_certs/**removed**.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/httpd/ssl/**removed**.key
```

They pointed me toward this forum post: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12251

Which suggests that it may be vsftpd is not closing the connections/processes properly and therefore, once they've connected ok through port 21, when it comes to trying to transfer data on one of the passive port numbers, it can't, because they are all in use. Makes sense.

So, I think I can sort of replicate that, but only when there is a connection error mid-transfer.

With a starting point, of nobody connected, running `netstat -anp | grep vsftpd` gives me the following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21051/vsftpd
```

Now, if I connect from a client:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21051/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.200:21         MYIP:29354   ESTABLISHED 22302/vsftpd        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179539  22302/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179494  22303/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179493  22311/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179540  22311/vsftpd
```

So now we have the connection to port 21, which is correct.

Now if I started a file transfer:

```
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.200:10091      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22302/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21051/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.200:21         MYIP:29354   ESTABLISHED 22302/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.200:10091      MYIP:25260   ESTABLISHED 22303/vsftpd        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179539  22302/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179494  22303/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179493  22311/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179540  22311/vsftpd
```

So now we have the connection to port 10091, which is one of the passive ports.

If that transfer completes successfully, then that connection on port 10091 disappears and all is well.

However, i've noticed that sometimes there is a timeout and the file transfer gets interrupted, and when that happens, even if I then disconnect and close the ftp client, I find that those connections are still open (it has also opened 2 more in its attempts to reconnect after the timeout issue):

```
tcp        1      0 172.31.1.200:10090      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22595/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.200:10091      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22302/vsftpd        
tcp        1      0 172.31.1.200:10094      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22548/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21051/vsftpd        
tcp        1      0 172.31.1.200:21         MYIP:29354   CLOSE_WAIT  22302/vsftpd        
tcp        1      0 172.31.1.200:21         MYIP:37584   CLOSE_WAIT  22595/vsftpd        
tcp        1      0 172.31.1.200:21         MYIP:33453   CLOSE_WAIT  22548/vsftpd        
tcp        0      0 172.31.1.200:10091      MYIP:25260   ESTABLISHED 22303/vsftpd        
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179539  22302/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5181389  22557/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179494  22303/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5182639  22600/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5182675  22600/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5181973  22557/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179493  22311/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5182674  22595/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5182640  22596/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5179540  22311/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5181390  22549/vsftpd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     5181972  22548/vsftpd
```

So what I am thinking is happening here, is that for some reason the transfers are experiencing issues and getting cut off sometimes, which is then leaving those connections still open on the server, then when it keeps trying again, it eventually uses up all 5 of the passive port numbers, and it then can't do anything.

So my question is two-fold. Firstly, is there any way to work out what might be causing these timeouts? I thought at first it was just on my end, because i'm testing this off a mobile hotspot, but it would make sense if that's what is happening with the client as well (it's an automated script they run a few times a day).

And secondly, is there anything I can do to stop those connections being kept open and clogging up the ports like that?

**Information**

Server is CentOS 7

vsftpd is version 3.0.2

Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks.

Comment: [Packet loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss)?

Comment: Is there a way for me to tell from the server, or from the client side? Or would the network guys need to look at that?

Comment: `ping <hostname>`. The packet numbers should increment, i.e., 1, 2, 3 etc. If some packets are omitted then this could indicate packet loss.

Comment: @ConnWarwicker what's the WinSCP version? Also: check the clients (WinSCPs) logfiles. Sometimes there are problems closing connections with WinSCP. Could you reproduce the error using a different client?